# Ionic how to add scroll to card

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile

Maybe someone could help me..I have form in ion-card which is inside the ion-content. When I'm testing on android keyboard is pushing content up so in manifest I set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" now content is not pushed but now I want to add scroll because keyboard is hiding some content.,problem is that applying scrollY="true" to ion-content or add ion-scroll tag is not having any effect. Maybe someone have idea how to add scroll to card when keyboard is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to solve the problem by setting the following css code on my `ion-card` :

```
ion-card {
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Also remove the `ion-card-content` element, and apply the following css code on the `ion-list` :

```
ion-list {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```